# How to convert a string to bytes with hexadecimal representation in Python?

Tags: python, string, hex, byte

I am a very beginner at Python.
I have a string that is "TEST00000001" and its length is 12. I want to convert this string to a byte with a hexadecimal representation like this b'\x54\x45\x53\x54\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\30\x30\x31'.  As you can see, the length of the two objects has not changed.

So far, I am successfully converting my string to bytes. But the length of converted bytes is 24 instead of 12.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
sample_string = "TEST00000001"
output = ''.join(hex(ord(character_index))[2:] for character_index in sample_string)
hex_bytes = bytes(output, 'ascii')
print(hex_bytes)  # Output of this line is: b'544553543030303030303031'
print(len(hex_bytes))  # Length of my output is: 24
```

Can someone help me about converting my string to a byte object (in hex representation) without changing its length?

Comment: Show what you have tried. There's an obvious grouping of pairs of chars - so use that to work our a solution.

Comment: What's `hex_string2`? You've used `output` but not specified its initial value.

Comment: @aneroid Sorry i made a mistake while copying the code. Fixed now

Comment: Your question says _`I have a string which is "544553543030303030303031"`_ and then you put _`hex_string2 = "TEST00000001"`_ in the code :-/

Comment: After a long time I edited and clarified the question despite your feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string into bytes in Python, use `bytes` directly on the string. Don’t call `ord` or `hex` on the characters:

```
hex_string2 = "TEST00000001"
byte_data = bytes(hex_string2, 'ascii')
print(len(byte_data))
# 12
```

And the output is indeed the same as `b'\x54\x45\x53\x54\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31'`:

```
byte_data == b'\x54\x45\x53\x54\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31'
# True
```

---

By contrast, if your input is a string of bytes in padded hexadecimal representation, you need to *decode* that representation (e.g. using `binascii`):

```
import binascii
binascii.unhexlify(b'544553543030303030303031')
# b'TEST00000001'
```

Or `codecs`:

```
import codecs
codecs.decode('544553543030303030303031', 'hex')
# b'TEST00000001'
```

Answer (score 0):

A byte is a byte, no matter the architecture.
As far as I have been unable to reproduce your problems, I've seen this:

```
>>> hex_string2 = "TEST00000001"
>>> byte_data = bytes(hex_string2, 'ascii')
>>> print(byte_data) #/ b'544553543030303030303031'
b'TEST00000001'
>>> print(len(byte_data)) #24
12
```

The above works, as expected.
Can it be, that in your original post, you have a different variable that you are referencing and setting before (i.e. variable output)?

```
byte_data = bytes(output, 'ascii')
```

Beacause if you do:

```
>>> hex_string2.encode("hex")
'544553543030303030303031'
```

Now if you would want a list of two digit decimals, then

```
>>> [this.encode("hex") for this in byte_data]
['54', '45', '53', '54', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '31']
```

Would this be something you are trying to get?

Comment: This doesn’t work any more: `str.decode('hex')` is Python 2 only.

Comment: Yeah, true, Ive tested the behavior in both for the previous example and left my prompt at python2, but the general idea that the above is fine (i.e. using the bytes()) is there. I'll edit the reply to reflect the versions.